# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index (DECIMAL)

Tags: c#, indexing, decimal

```
SalesOrderEntry rey = new SalesOrderEntry(id, cash);
total = Convert.ToInt32(lblCustomersCash.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(lblSubtotal.Text);

if (total > cash)
{
    DGVTOTAL.DataSource = ProductREPO.GETORDERTOTALLIST();

    for (int i = 0; i < DGVORDER.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        SalesOrderEntry see = new SalesOrderEntry(id, cash);
        //CASH = 649 and im selecting an item that is equivalent to 30

        sum2 = Convert.ToInt32(DGVORDER.Rows[i].Cells["OrderedProductPrice"].Value);

        dgvGetID.DataSource = SalesORDERREPO.weredone(id);
        decimal newcash = int.Parse(dgvGetID.Rows[0].Cells["Cash"].Value.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show("NEW BALANCE CASH: " + newcash);
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hey your Cash is not ENOUGH to Buy this ITEM");
}
```

i want to Display its new Cash balance.. deductive to its subtotal.. but im having this ERROR:

`<Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index>`

Comment: EVERY CHARACTERS OF LETTERS YOU SENT THAT CAN HELP ME.. GREATLY APPRECIATED 

THANKS , CHEERS :D

Comment: Where does the error occur? Have you debugged?

Comment: I would guess that it's on the line: `decimal newcash = int.Parse(dgvGetID.Rows[0].Cells["Cash"].Value.ToString());` Are you positive that `dgvGetID.Rows` has at least one entry?

Answer (score 2):

Are uou sure dgvGetID contains item?

Comment: THANKS SIR BUT THIS IS CLOSED.. PROBLEM IS FIXED

Comment: YOU WILL NOW HAVE MORE TIME TO FIX YOUR CAPS PROBLEM :D

Answer (score 0):

DataGridViews rows start at element 0 not element 1 and as such when trying to access the 6th element you would need to access DGV.Rows[5] not DGV.Rows[6] while DataGridViews.Rows.Count returns the number of rows starting at 1 and not 0.

EDIT:

TO clarify to commenter

The datagridview rows array starts at the element 0 so datagridview1.Rows[0] gives the first row of the DGV (DataGridView).

In the code supplied the poster loops through until DGV.ROWS.COUNT which will return the non-zero based count. By that I mean if there are 6 rows then count returns 6 BUT the last row in the DGV.ROWS array is accessed by DGV.Rows[5] because the ROWS array is zero-based (starts at 0) so Rows[0] is the first row, Rows[1] second row etc...
Hopefully that clears it up for people

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Have expanded to hopefully clarify what I meant.

Comment: I still do not understand how that causes the problem. Yes, a Count for 6 rows returns 6, and yes, Rows[index] is 0-based. That doesn't explain the cause of the problem to me. The for-loop loops while i < count, so that loops while i < 6, which results in a last value of 5. Seems correct to me.